# Rails subclassing and STI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, inheritance, sti

I'm working on a Rails project `OldApp` that's using STI for some class Foo.
At the moment we have a big, incremental, rewrite going on. To ease the pain we chose a rather unconventional approach. The new, namespaced, application `NewApp` lives as an engine in `OldApp` for now.

The models we're going to reuse in `NewApp` have been created in `NewApp` and `OldApp` now uses these models as their parent classes. Why? Now we can move and refactor code from `OldApp`s models to the new ones, `OldApp` still works, the tests from `OldApp` ensure that the refactoring in `NewApp` doesn't break stuff and `OldApp` basically works as a todo-list (if everything from `OldApp` is gone, we're done). However ;-)

The problem is, STI kinda kills this (otherwise surprisingly nicely working) approach at the moment.

```
   class OldApp::Foo < NewApp::Foo; end
   class NewApp::Foo < ActiveRecord::Base; end

   # in the console
   OldApp::Foo.count #=> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `foos` WHERE `foos`.`type` IN ('Foo')
   NewApp::Foo.count #=> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `foos`
```

of course, `OldApp::Foo` does this, because it's assuming it's just a STIish subclass of `NewApp::Foo` and not *the* base `Foo` class for `NewApp`. Disabling STI completly for `Whatever::Foo` doesn't work either because, well, in fact we *are* using STI for `Foo`.

I'm basically looking for something to tell `NewApp::Foo` that it's the base class for the STI chain.

Does this make sense? A little hard to explain...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an abstract base class and let inherit `OldApp::Foo` and `NewApp::Foo` from it would do the trick:

```
class NewApp::FooBase < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.abstract_class = true
end

class NewApp::Foo < NewApp::FooBase; end
class OldApp::Foo < NewApp::FooBase; end
```

You would put all your refactored code in the base class so that `OldApp::Foo` and `NewApp::Foo` act as starting point for STI.